# Codeigniter database error

Tags: php, codeigniter

My site has working fine for a while but today its shows this database error and i have no clue what it means

"A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1030

Got error 28 from storage engine"

Has any one had this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be that space has run out on the server or some other problem with the database that needs attention.

If you logon to the server and restart the mysql server this should help.

Here is a good guide to fixing the problem:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-error-28-and-solution/

Stop mysql server

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

b) Check filesystem and /tmp directories:

```
$ df -h
$ cd /tmp
$ df -h /tmp
```

c) Remove files from /tmp to free up space:

```
# cd /tmp
# rm -rf *
```

d) Look into /var/log directory and remove or compress logs file.

e) Use myisamchk command to check and repair of ISAM table:

```
# cd /var/lib/mysql
# myisamchk
```

f) Increase disk space (add new hard disk or remove unwanted software(s) )

g) Start the mysql server:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: the site is hosted on shared hosting, but i'll try to repair the database. The backend still works